# Vercel next.js deployment function logs without third party

Tags: node.js, next.js, serverless, vercel

Been toying around with Vercel for deployment and really like the simplicity. Maybe I am not seeing something here, but how can I get visibility into a function without piping to a third-party?

I've got this `pages/api/hello.js`-api

```
export default (req, res) => {
    console.log("yolo");
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.json({ name: "John Doe" });
};
```

I can then see the following results in the dashboard. But where or how could I see the `yolo` and I missing something here? Is there a different way for proper debugging?

[image]

Comment: Going off forums, seems to be a known issue which they don't seem to be hurrying to fix. Found this package someone added as a work-around: https://logs.now.sh/

Comment: thx! Doesn't really seem to be working for me. I can connect to my secret, but its not streaming anything. Any clues?

Comment: Let me have a quick dig...

Comment: I have added an answer containing solution which worked for me, let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have created the same setup here:

https://github.com/timothyclifford/offsets/blob/master/pages/api/hello.js

Pushed this to Vercel and can see the console logs being printed out correctly:

[image]

Comment: Thx. It actually did work for me too at some point, not sure what had changed.

Answer (score 4):

While Vercel seems to have fixed the issue with `console.log` output not showing up in their online dashboard, I still found it pretty frustrating how quickly logs disappeared from their dashboard.

I found using `vercel logs --follow <deployment-name>` from my terminal to be more useful for debugging issues with my deployed functions.

Comment: For whatever reason, I'm unable to see logs from my Python based serverless functions through the UI. Using the command you provided, however, does work. Thanks for the info.